# Rails - has_many through, STI, and scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following models:

```rb
    create_table :production_actions do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :key
    end

    create_table :production_attributes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :key
      t.string :type
    end

    create_table :production_items do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :line_items_production_items do |t|
      t.references :line_item, null: false
      t.references :production_item, null: false
    end
    add_index(:line_items_production_items, [:line_item_id, :production_item_id], unique: true, name: 'line_items_production_items_unique')

    create_table :production_attributes_production_items do |t|
      t.references :production_attribute, null: false, index: {name: 'production_items_on_production_attribute_id'}
      t.references :production_item, null: false, index: {name: 'production_attributes_on_production_item_id'}
    end
    add_index(:production_attributes_production_items, [:production_attribute_id, :production_item_id], unique: true, name: 'production_attributes_production_items_unique')

    create_table :production_actions_production_items do |t|
      t.references :production_action, null: false, index: {name: 'production_items_on_production_action_id'}
      t.references :production_item, null: false, index: {name: 'production_actions_on_production_item_id'}
    end
    add_index(:production_actions_production_items, [:production_action_id, :production_item_id], unique: true, name: 'production_actions_production_items_unique')
```

```rb
  class ProductionAttributeProductionItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :production_attribute, class_name: "ProductionAttribute::Base"
    belongs_to :production_item, class_name: "ProductionItem::Base"
  end
```

```rb
  module ProductionItem
    class Base < ApplicationRecord
      self.table_name = "production_items"

      has_many :production_attribute_production_items, class_name: "ProductionAttributeProductionItem"
      has_many :production_attributes, class_name: "ProductionAttribute::Base", through: :production_attribute_production_items

  end
```

```rb
  module ProductionAttribute
    class Base < ApplicationRecord
      self.table_name = "production_attributes"


    end
  end
```

```rb
  module ProductionAttribute
    class PaperType < ProductionAttribute::Base

    end
  end
```

```rb
  module ProductionItem
    class Paper < ProductionItem::Base
              has_one :paper_type, -> { where(type: "ProductionAttribute::PaperType")},
                class_name: "ProductionAttribute::PaperType", foreign_key: :product_attribute_id,
                through: :production_attributes, inverse_of: :product_attribute

    end
  end
```

There are many types of `production_items` that are all saved in a table via STI. There are also many types of `production_attributes` all saved in a table via STI. A `production_item` has (and belongs to) many `production_attributes`. Based off the subclass, i want to create specific `product_attribute` associations based off the type of  `production_item`. for instance, a paper production_item will have a paper_type product_attribute.

my problem is i am trying to get the specific scoped associations like `paper.paper_type` to work but i am having a hard time. If i do something like the following i get an error:

```
[1] pry(main)> p = ProductionItem::Paper.new
   (0.3ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
=> #<ProductionItem::Paper:0x00005602a669b528
 id: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
[2] pry(main)> p.paper_type
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "paper_type" or :paper_type in model ProductionAttribute::Base. Try 'has_many :paper_type, :through => :production_attributes, :source => <name>'. Is it one of jobs?
from /home/USERNAME/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.4/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:920:in `check_validity!'
```

Ive tried a few things without any luck. any idea why this isnt working?

Answer (score 0):

Did you store the foreign keys in the models that are in the database?

To use belongs_to, has_many and has_one you need to store these values in some way in the database.

For example, in ProductionItem you don't necessarily need to store the ids of other objects (it would be interesting, but it would be something similar to an array). But if you decide not to do this above, you must save the id of each ProductionItem in the object that belongs to it.

Comment: From what I read, you do not store these ids in the ProductItem paper and it raises an error stating that it was unable to find the "source" of the association.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your response to this. The IDs are stored in the join table `ProductionAttributeProductionItem`. I edited the above to incude the migration

Comment: Ok, so i get what you're saying by adding a source. now im facing the issue that my `source_type` is a STI table. i'm not sure how to solve for that